# Must set a strong reference to null after use in Java when using WeakReference?

Tags: java, android, weak-references

I was reading [this](http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.refobj) due to some memory issues I was having in my code relating to weak references, when I came across this little note:

> *You have to explicitly set that strong reference to null after use:*
>
> This one isn't so obvious: you might think that a strong reference ceases to exist once it goes out of scope. However, the JVM isn't required to do so, and for efficiency's sake, won't. The strong reference remains in the stack frame, and can get in the way of garbage collection.

Is this still true? If I do something like:

```
void foo(){
    Object obj = weakRef.get();
    doStuffWith(obj);
}
```

Is it required that I set `obj = null` when I'm done with the method, or else I'll leak obj?

Comment: No, you don't have to set the reference to null. The section that you quoted is misleading as written: it belongs with the "circuit breaker" example that appears several paragraphs down. I'm not sure when/why I moved it, but will edit the document and republish.

Comment: @kdgregory - feel free to move your comment to an answer when you get a chance.

Comment: @kdgregory "for now all you need to know is that Java uses a form of mark-sweep-compact garbage collection" That totally depends on the implementation and even actually looking at Hotspot today shows that this isn't really true (there are half a dozen or so different algorithms and god knows how many possible combinations by now). Or more important: By default the young generation uses a stop&copy gc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that JVM isn't required to do so. As a matter of fact, JVM isn't required to do GC at all.

But a JVM that doesn't nullify a local reference is as unreasonable as a JVM that doesn't do GC.

(Well, there are people who give gigantic memory to JVM, and turn off GC completely; they simply restart the app every N days.)